# Why can't I create an OpenGL ES 3.0 context using SDL2?

Tags: opengl-es, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2 2.0.2 on Debian stable, and I'm trying to acquire an OpenGL ES 3.0 context with it. This works if I request an OpenGL ES 2.0 context, but not if I directly request an OpenGL ES 3.0 context.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(
    int argc,
    char **argv
) {
    SDL_GLContext context;
    int rc;
    const GLubyte *version;
    SDL_Window *window;

    rc = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    if (rc < 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    atexit(SDL_Quit);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);
#ifdef THIS_SHOULD_WORK_TOO
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);
#else
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);
#endif

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL", 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);

    if (version == 0) {
        printf(
            "Unable to get OpenGL ES version string: %d\n",
            glGetError()
        );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Version string: %s\n", version);

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I compile this normally, it requests an OpenGL ES 2.0 context, and the program receives an OpenGL ES 3.0 context:

```
$ c99 example.c -lSDL2 -lGLESv2
$ ./a.out 
Version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
```

However, when I request an OpenGL ES 3.0 context, this program fails without a clear error message:

```
$ c99 -DTHIS_SHOULD_WORK_TOO example.c -lSDL2 -lGLESv2
$ ./a.out
Unable to get OpenGL ES version string: 0
```

Why is this?

I doubt it is because of `-lGLESv2`, mostly because the OpenGL ES context reports that it is version 3.0, and because platforms that do ship a `libGLESv3.so` ship it as a symlink it to `libGLESv2.so` ([Android does this](http://www.2net.co.uk/tutorial/android-egl-cgf-is-dead), for example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [a bug in SDL2](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2865):

> SDL's EGL code (used for OpenGL ES context creation on Windows / Linux / Android / etc.) only seems to properly support OpenGL ES 1 and 2 contexts.
>
> In particular, the current code sets the EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE config attribute to EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT if GLES2 is requested and EGL_OPENGL_ES_BIT in all other cases. It never uses EGL_OPENGL_ES3_BIT / EGL_OPENGL_ES3_BIT_KHR even when GLES3.0+ is requested. It also doesn't use EGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_KHR to set the version to 3.1 rather than 3.0 in SDL_EGL_CreateContext, when 3.1 is requested.

This means that a request for OpenGL ES 3.0 is translated into a request for OpenGL ES 1.0. Since OpenGL ES 3.0 is backwards incompatible with OpenGL ES 1.0, the request eventually fails (I think).

[The fix](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/6027a65e8528) has been merged into the master branch, and is scheduled to be released [as part of SDL2 version 2.0.4](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/d3ad01d50bf0/WhatsNew.txt):

> - Added EGL_KHR_create_context support to allow OpenGL ES version selection on some platforms